# How can I fix these php errors after altering routes.php in config folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I was working on making my routes file dynamically updated from the database. Unfortunately, my cunning plan has caused some problems.

I added this line to the end of routes.php in the config file:

```
include_once APPPATH . "cache/routes.php";
```

The routes.php file in the cache folder is getting updated automatically which is nice. Currently, it looks likes this:

```
$route["index"] = "pages/index/1";
```

$route["About Us/subpagetest"] = "pages/index/4";
$route["About Us"] = "pages/index/3";

The problem is, i'm getting these errors at the top of every page:

> > A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/jshultz/public_html/application/cache/routes.php:3)
>
> Filename: core/Security.php
>
> Line Number: 188
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/jshultz/public_html/application/cache/routes.php:3)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 672

I thought maybe it was a permissions error but I don't know? I've tried changing the permissions to the file but that hasn't changed anything. Any ideas?

EDIT:

OK, so routes.php in the application/cache folder needs to have the opening

Here's the CORRECTED code that creates the routes.php file in the cache folder:

```
public function save_routes()
        {

            // this simply returns all the pages from my database
            $routes = $this->Pages_model->get_all($this->siteid);

            // write out the PHP array to the file with help from the file helper
            if ( !empty( $routes ) )
            {
                // for every page in the database, get the route using the recursive function - _get_route()
                foreach( $routes->result_array() as $route )
                {
                    $data[] = '$route["' . $this->_get_route($route['pageid']) . '"] = "' . "pages/index/{$route['pageid']}" . '";';
                }

                $output = "<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');\n";

                $output .= implode("\n", $data);

                $this->load->helper('file');
                write_file(APPPATH . "cache/routes.php", $output);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add `<?php` in the begining of file and remove `Byte Order Mark` from

```
/home/jshultz/public_html/application/cache/routes.php
```

and don't use PHP closing tag **?>** in that file. Using **?>** will force interpreter to consider characters after the tag as text output.

Comment: I don't see where I can remove the byte Order Mark? Also, none of my php files use the ?> closing tag. :(

Comment: if you are using Vim it's *:set nobomb*

Comment: Ok, I just checked and there was no Byte Order Marks.

Comment: Does /home/jshultz/public_html/application/cache/routes.php start with an opening tag **<?php**

Comment: No. And I feel pretty stupid for that. I just tried it and it did fix it. but after my script runs it removes the opening tag.

Comment: I updated the question with the controller that creates the routes.php file in the cache folder.

Comment: $output = '<?php' . PHP_EOL . implode("\n", $data); // should fix it

Comment: We had a similar idea. this is what I ended up doing:

$output = "<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');";

    $output .= implode("\n", $data);

Comment: Thank you for your help. I couldn't have done it without you. I was totally missing the obvious this time. ;)